# AWS SNS Invalid parameter phone number

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, web, amazon-sns

i am trying to learn aws sns service to send sms from my web application.
I am working on localhost.

```
$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'iam_key',
        'secret' => 'iam_secret',
    ),
    'region' => 'ap-south-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
    'version' => 'latest',
    'http' => ['verify'=>false]
);
$sns = \Aws\Sns\SnsClient::factory($params);

$msgattributes = [
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'Klassroom',
        ],
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
        ]
    ];

$payload = array(
        'Message' => "HK test",
        "PhoneNumber" => "1234567890",
        'MessageAttributes' => $msgattributes
    );

$result = $sns->publish($payload);
```

i want to send sms directly on number. this code is giving this error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Sns\Exception\SnsException' with message 'Error executing "Publish" on "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:   Sender `InvalidPara (truncated...) InvalidParameter (client): Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +1234567890 is not valid to publish to -   Sender InvalidParameter Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: +1234567890 is not valid to publish to  13e181c2-a20f-5e77-9c8e-d38c55c50266  ' exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: POST https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com resulted in a 400 Bad Request`

i don't know why....

Comment: I would guess that the phone number first has to sign up for SNS notifications.

Comment: can't we send sms directly on number using aws sns service??

Answer (score 0):

I believe a phone number for AWS has to include the country code.

For instance if my phone number is `(999) 365-6721` it would be `+19993656721` (for US)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue even though I called the API with a valid phone number prefixed with correct country code (for example +57xxxxxxxxxx).

Then I figured out after running through some threads on the internet that it was only because of the ***incorrect REGION_CODE*** (for example **us-west-1** instead of **us-east-1**) used during the instantiation of SNSClient class.

```
    @Bean
public AmazonSNS snsClient() {
    return AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials())).build();
}
```

Refer to the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html) to find the right region code for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the region that supported SMS for AWS SNS.

More information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html

Answer (score 0):

### SMS Sandbox Mode

When you start off using SNS for the first time for sending SMS, it starts in the so called 'Sandbox Mode'.

In this mode, you must *verify the phone numbers* that you intend to use.

If you are using SMS in Sandbox Mode and try to send an SMS via SNS to an unverified number, you will get the error

[image: SMS Sandbox Mode]

This prevents unsolicited text messaging.

If you try to create an SMS subscription to an SNS topic without a phone number that's been verified you will indeed receive the error:

```
Enter a valid mobile number
```

The phone number is valid. You just need to verify it first, as described above, before you can create this subscription in SNS

[image: Enter a valid mobile number]

Of course, the same principle applies, when you're trying to achieve this via code.