# How to set the from number on AWS SNS (Using PHP v3 SDK)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

## Setup

I've download the [aws.zip file for AWS V3 SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_installation.html) and extracted it into my project's folder and connected it's auto-loader into my auto-loader. I've also gone though all of the steps to create an AWS account, along with setting up SNS including acquiring a phone number to use. All of the examples work has shown in the sanity check.

There is a little dark corner that you should know about. You need to create a `credentials` file in your `~/.aws/` directory. If you are using this from a php-fpm context, that home directory might be your `/var/www/` directory so you should put your credential files under `/var/www/.aws/`.

More information on the configuration file can be found here ... [AWS Command Line Interface - Configuration and credential file settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html).

## Sanity Check

Following the examples from the [AWS SNS Documentation - Publish to a Text Message (SMS Message)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/sns-examples-sending-sms.html#publish-to-a-text-message-sms-message).

**Test-AWS-SNS.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Sns\SnsClient; 
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$SnSclient = new SnsClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2010-03-31'
]);

$message = 'This message is sent from a Amazon SNS code sample.';
$phone = '+1AAALLL####';

try {
    $result = $SnSclient->publish([
        'Message' => $message,
        'PhoneNumber' => $phone,
    ]);
    var_dump($result);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

(Notes: `+1AAALLL####` actually points to my cell phone number, but I'm obviously not going to put that here.)

## The Problem

The problem is that there is no documentation for how to send a text message from one of the numbers that I own from AWS' SNS Long Code list. It always comes from the first phone number in the list and I can't find any documentation on how to change the number to another one. Some help here would be great.

## Prior research

Obviously, I've been all over the documentation and searched Stack Overflow as well.
[This one is pretty close, as it sets a SenderID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568343/aws-sns-invalid-parameter-phone-number). Their documentation
[mentions how to do it as an optional number 9 next to the sender ID from above](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html)
But I do know that it is possible, because they added the feature on [Oct 23, 2020 - Amazon SNS now supports selecting the origination number when sending SMS messages](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-sns-now-supports-selecting-the-origination-number-when-sending-sms-messages/) -- They just haven't put any code samples.

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the solutions to this, after much looking around and rubber ducking the problem while typing into the text box above, is to use a couple of different answers together. The Stack Overflow thread mentioned in prior research about setting the SenderID was very helpful to atleast getting the raw information into the AWS SDK.

```
$params = [
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'iam_key',
        'secret' => 'iam_secret',
    ],
    'region' => 'ap-south-1', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
    'version' => 'latest',
    'http' => ['verify' => false]
];
$sns = \Aws\Sns\SnsClient::factory($params);

$msgattributes = [
    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
        'DataType' => 'String',
        'StringValue' => 'Klassroom',
    ],
    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
        'DataType' => 'String',
        'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
    ]
];

$payload = [
    'Message' => 'HK test',
    'PhoneNumber' => '1234567890',
    'MessageAttributes' => $msgattributes
];

$result = $sns->publish($payload);
```

If you scroll into the [SMS Publish To Phone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html#sms_publish_sdk) documentation, you'll see the string used above `AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID` and the next item down is ... `AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber` ... So maybe that will work?

## IT'S WORKING! IT'S WORKING!

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Sns\SnsClient; 
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$SnSclient = new SnsClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2010-03-31'
]);

$msgAttributes = [
    'AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber' => [
        'DataType' => 'String',
        'StringValue' => '+1XXXYYYZZZZ',
    ]
];

$message = 'This message is sent from a Amazon SNS code sample.';
$phone = '+1AAALLL####';

try {
    $result = $SnSclient->publish([
        'Message' => $message,
        'PhoneNumber' => $phone,
        'MessageAttributes' => $msgAttributes
    ]);
    var_dump($result);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Note: Obviously, `+1XXXYYYZZZZ` is a number from my already established long code list, and just like before `+1AAALLL####` is my phone number or the phone number of the person I want to send the text message to.

Comment: I wish I could give more than one upvote. I've been struggling with this for a while now and only just found this question. And it worked for me. Thanks!